# Error when I try to convert string column to float column

Tags: sql-server, string, type-conversion

I have a table with a column A.
I would like to change the datatype from string to float.
My column A looks like this:

```
A
143
1,440
19,630
12
```

...
When I try to run my code:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table1]
ALTER COLUMN [A] FLOAT
```

I always get this error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

Comment: Numbers don't have commas. Remove those first using `REPLACE`.

Comment: sql servers uses a dot `. ` in stead of a comma `, ` for floats, so you must replace these first

Answer (score 1):

It is clear in error that `varchar` value is not converting into `float`.  Since `,` is not allowed in `int, float, decimal` type values, so first need to replace your `,` .

Instead of this you may try this.

```
  update table set A = Replace( A, ',', '' )
```

Or

```
  update table set A = Replace( A, ',', '.' )
```

Whichever condition suits you better.

After that convert your column.

```
  ALTER TABLE [Table1]
  ALTER COLUMN [A] FLOAT
```